# Get bootstrap grid to be centered without affecting the symmetry of items in container

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, grid

I have 4 graphs that are in 2 x 2  and they're nicely laid out but they're pushed to the left side of the screen. When I try to add a column (and maybe thisis where I am going wrong) Everything gets jumbled up.  I want a column of width 2 at the left of both rows, then a 2 x 2 grid containing 4 charts.

[image]

```
 <div class="container-fluid">

     </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <img src="fig1.png" alt="Bootcamp" width="450" height="350">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <img src="fig2.png" alt="Bootcamp" width="450" height="350">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <div>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img src="fig3.png" alt="Bootcamp" width="450" height="350">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img src="fig4.png" alt="Bootcamp" width="450" height="350">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I was getting close, but I had the <div class="col-sm-2"> in the wrong spot. I was getting there. Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the code based on your requirement. Also, to make your content center, I add in class `justify-content-center` to class `row` div.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-sm-2"> TEXT 1 </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="fig1.png" alt="Bootcamp" width="450" height="350">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="fig2.png" alt="Bootcamp" width="450" height="350">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-sm-2"> TEXT 2 </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="fig3.png" alt="Bootcamp" width="450" height="350">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="fig4.png" alt="Bootcamp" width="450" height="350">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, either of these should work:

Option 1:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 bg-dark text-light">
            <div>
                <p>Text 1</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>Text 2</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <!-- Add another row inside the remaining space, then add the 2 columns for graphs -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <img src="img1.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Bootcamp">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <img src="img2.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Bootcamp">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <img src="img3.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Bootcamp">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <img src="img4.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Bootcamp">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which would produce

[image: Layout 1]
Option 2:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 bg-dark text-light">
            <div>
                <p>Text 1</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <img src="img1.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Bootcamp">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <img src="img2.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Bootcamp">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Add second row -->
        <div class="col-sm-2 bg-dark text-light">
            <div>
                <p>Text 2</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <img src="img3.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Bootcamp">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <img src="img4.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Bootcamp">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which would produce

[image: Layout 2]

Hope it helps!

Comment: You understand very correctly; either I explained it well, or you're very intuitive. I'll go with the latter since I'm generally terrible at explaining things. ;)
Thank you!!!!